# CSS table with fixed column widths and max height

Tags: css, html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to create a table with fixed column widths, and also a fixed maximum height, which scrolls beyond the maximum height.

Reading around, I would use table-layout:fixed and specify the column widths to accomplish the first task. I would set max-height, overflow:auto and display:block on the table to accomplish the second.

However, these don't seem to be working together. The columns are approximately half of the intended width.

My attempt:
https://jsfiddle.net/d3y5g9fq/

```
<table>
<colgroup>
  <col style="width: 30%">
  <col style="width: 50%">
  <col style="width: 20%">
</colgroup>
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>Col A</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
    <th>Col C</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

```
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you change the column widths from percentages to viewport width (`vw`) it should work as intended, but not quite as expected. Viewport sizes are supposed to size it according to the size of the full viewport, but if you wrap it in a `div` with a `width` of 70%, it will work like a percentage instead of a `vw` in this scenario.

Using `vw` with a parent `width` of 100%:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi! </p>
<table>
<colgroup>
  <col style="width: 30vw">
  <col style="width: 50vw">
  <col style="width: 20vw">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Col A</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
    <th>Col C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using `vw` with a parent `width` of 70%:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi! </p>
<div style="width: 70%">
<table>
<colgroup>
  <col style="width: 30vw">
  <col style="width: 50vw">
  <col style="width: 20vw">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Col A</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
    <th>Col C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
```

Not quite what you would expect... why? There are a very tiny amount of scenarios where `vw` and `vh` do not work as intended. I've never quite found out *why* myself, but I would guess it is misinterpreting the viewport as a single element for some reason.

If you want to be syntactically correct, you could also use `em` instead of `vw`, which will give you the exact same results:

Using `em` with a parent `width` of 100%:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi! </p>
<table>
<colgroup>
  <col style="width: 30em">
  <col style="width: 50em">
  <col style="width: 20em">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Col A</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
    <th>Col C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Using `em` with a parent `width` of 70%:

```css
table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  display: block;
  max-height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}

p {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}

table, td, th {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<p>Hi! </p>
<div style="width: 70%">
<table>
<colgroup>
  <col style="width: 30em">
  <col style="width: 50em">
  <col style="width: 20em">
</colgroup>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <th>Col A</th>
    <th>Col B</th>
    <th>Col C</th>
  </tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div>
```

Comment: Wow! I thought vw was computed from the entire page size ("viewport width"). I guess I was wrong... why does this still work even when I wrap the table in a div with width:70%?

Comment: I've edited my answer to expand on it a bit further. If you want to be syntactically correct, you could use `em` instead of `vw`. There are a few situations where viewport sizes do not work as intended, so don't make this "broken" situation change your understanding of `vw` and `vh`. 99% of the time, it is computed using the entire page size.